# 2 sendkeys in 1 line for selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have following scenario where I have to perform 2 actions on the same element.

```
Element.SendKeys("string")
Element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
```

Can we do something like

```
Element.SendKeys("string").Sendkeys(keys.Enter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
Element.SendKeys("string" + Keys.Enter)
```